# how to overwrite the renderlayer.php in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides

When i try to overwrite the Renderlayer.php of module-swatches I am getting error

```
[2018-09-24 06:48:41] report.CRITICAL: Warning: Declaration of Kygo\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered::getOptionViewData(Kygo\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\FilterItem $filterItem, Kygo\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\Option $swatchOption) should be compatible with Magento\Swatches\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered::getOptionViewData(Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item $filterItem, Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Option $swatchOption) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/kygolife/app/code/Kygo/Swatches/Block/LayeredNavigation/RenderLayered.php on line 14 [] []
```

How to overwrite that file.

Comment: How you overwrite, write more.

Comment: Please  share your rewrite ckass

Comment: I have mentioned in di.xml and in the block have written code  class RenderLayered extends \CustomSidebar\LayeredNavigation\Block\LayeredNavigation\RenderLayered
{
    protected function getOptionViewData(FilterItem $filterItem, Option $swatchOption)
    {}}